# Trying to print a panel in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to print a panel that has pictureboxes, labels and textboxes. I want to print it on A4 paper so the panel has 595x842.
I have tried:

```
private void print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PrintPanel(panel1);   
}

private void PrintPanel(Panel pnl)
{
    PrintDialog myPrintDialog = new PrintDialog();
    System.Drawing.Bitmap memoryImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(pnl.Width, pnl.Height);
    pnl.DrawToBitmap(memoryImage, pnl.ClientRectangle);
    if (myPrintDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings values;
        values = myPrintDialog.PrinterSettings;
        myPrintDialog.Document = printDocument1;
        printDocument1.PrintController = new StandardPrintController();
        printDocument1.Print();
    }
    printDocument1.Dispose();
}
```

When I try to print it I go to the One Note and all I get is a white page. What seems to be the problem?

---

I modified the code a bit. Now I get some output but it's still not good...
This is the code I used:

```
private void print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument doc = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();
   doc.PrintPage += new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventHandler(doc_PrintPage);
   doc.Print();
}
    private void doc_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
   Panel grd = new Panel();
   Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(grd.Width, grd.Height, grd.CreateGraphics());
   grd.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, grd.Width, grd.Height));
   RectangleF bounds = e.PageSettings.PrintableArea;
   float factor = ((float)bmp.Height / (float)bmp.Width);
   e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, bounds.Left, bounds.Top, bounds.Width, factor * bounds.Width);
}
```

And I get this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HB1EH.png

Can someone help?

Comment: You draw the panel into `memoryImage` but then you never use it.

Comment: So...What should I do with it? I'm sorry but I'm not experienced >.<

Comment: You did not post your event handler for the PrintDocument.PrintPage event.  Probably because you forgot to write it.  And yes, that produces nothing but a white page.

Comment: _A4 paper so the panel has 595x842_ Um, what? Pixels, mm, pica, point..? When printing the unit will be one thing to look out for.

Comment: Pixels...And I still don't get where should the memoryImage be used...Can someone correct the code?

Comment: The code is not so much wrong but incomplete: You need to code the `PrintPage` event. Here you use the usual `Graphics` commands to put stuff onto the page, the images, one by one, text, borders etc..

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the wrong panel. Your code is creating a new empty panel and trying to print that (which it successfully does).  You need to reference the existing panel you want to print:

```
void doc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e) {
  using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(panel1.ClientSize.Width, panel1.ClientSize.Height)) {
    panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, panel1.ClientRectangle);
    RectangleF bounds = e.PageSettings.PrintableArea;
    float factor = ((float)bmp.Height / (float)bmp.Width);
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, bounds.Left, bounds.Top,
                              bounds.Width, factor * bounds.Width);
  }
}
```